# generate series of time ranges

Tags: postgresql, range-types

I know we can use Postgres's `generate_series()` function to produce a list of timestamps. Can we do the same to produce a list of time ranges directly without having to manually convert generated timestamps into time ranges like so?

```
SELECT tstzrange(
   time_stamp,
   time_stamp + '1 days'
   '[)'
) AS time_range
FROM generate_series(
   '2022-01-01'::TIMESTAMPTZ,
   '2022-02-01'::TIMESTAMPTZ,
   '1 days'
) tmp(time_stamp);
```

Comment: Hoping to avoid having to call tstzrange() in the SELECT clause to not repeat the “1 days” offset twice which in my real example is a more complicated function.

Answer (score 1):

Up to Postgres 14, there is **no** variant of `generate_series()` doing that. Check with:

```
SELECT oid::regprocedure   AS function_signature
     , prorettype::regtype AS return_type
FROM   pg_proc
where  proname = 'generate_series';
```

See:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46499873/939860)

You can produce `timestamp` or `timestamptz`, but not `date` or `tstzrange`.